# VBA validate list of emails using pattern

Tags: excel, vba, email, design-patterns

I have got list of emails in a cell separated by semi-colons and space but i have got the pattern which validates emails only if they are separated by semi-colons. Where do I insert the space to fit my pattern?

Example of emails:
aaa@bbb.com; ccc@eee.com; fff@ggg.com

Amount of email addresses in a single cell varies from 1 to 20

Pattern validating emails separated by semi-colons:

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+([;.](([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+)*$
```

Comment: Try it here and see if that works for you.  [;\s.]

Comment: Did not go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?
https://regex101.com/r/7IPvOB/1

`^\s?(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+([;.](([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+)*$`

Comment: Wow! Saving link to this tool for the future references.

Comment: Another very good page in my opinion is http://www.phpliveregex.com/ Even if it's called PHP, they use the same regexpatterns. What I like about this page is that it shows what the array will look like in a better way (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

You're making your life much more complicated than it needs to be.

```
Dim addresses 'As Variant
addresses = Split(addresses, ";")
```

Done. You have your addresses in an array (albeit with an extra space, but you can easily trim it). A regex will inevitably exclude valid emails, unless it's compliant with the RFC822 standard for email addresses, and [you don't want such a regex pattern in your code](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

> *The grammar described in RFC 822 is surprisingly complex. Implementing validation with regular expressions somewhat pushes the limits of what it is sensible to do with regular expressions [...]*

Comment: Agree with you on that you don't want to regex email generally. If the user writes an email incorrect, then that is their problem. Not mine. +1 from me.